# Compare string using int 16h Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios

I need to compare a string, with something I type on the keyboard at 16h interruption.  How could I compare?

```
keyboard:
  mov ah, 00h
  int 16h

  mov ah, 0Eh
  int 10h

  cmp al, 13
  je compare

  jmp keyboard

compare: 
  mov [si], al
  mov di, s1
  mov cx, s1_len
  cld
  repe cmpsb
  jecxz command_version

  call command_not_found

  jmp keyboard

command_version:
  ...

command_not_found:
  ...

s1 db 'version', 0
s1_len equ $- s1
```

The 16h 00h accepts characters only.

Comment: read into a buffer for `repe cmpsb`, or compare as you read one char at a time in a loop so you can detect a mismatch before the user types past the difference.

Comment: The code you have written writes all characters to the screen, but it does not store them into memory. You must of course write all characters to the memory before you can compare them.

Comment: How could I store it in memory?

Answer (score 0):

> How could I store it in memory?

1. Define a buffer with `Buf db 10 dup (0)`.
2. Fill it from your input loop:

   ```
       cld
       mov  di, Buf
   keyboard:
       mov  ah, 00h
       int  16h
       stosb
       mov  ah, 0Eh
       int  10h
       cmp  al, 13
       jne  keyboard
       mov  byte [di-1], 0  ; Replace the unsuitable 13
   ```
3. Compare both **ASCIIZ** (zero-terminated) strings

   ```
   compare: 
       mov  di, Buf
       mov  si, s1
       mov  cx, s1_len
       repe cmpsb
       je   command_version
   ```

Comment: It is not working, when I write at least one character written in the buffer, it gives me a strange value.  and he can't compare.

Comment: @AfonsoDolmen Make sure that the **segment registers** are setup correctly. In particular for this code to work, you need `DS` = `ES`.